# php strtotime turn 1970

Tags: php, date, strtotime

I have a date like this:

```
11 Jun 2017
```

I want to format it like

```
11.06.2017
```

I try `strtotime` but turn 1970

```
$arrival = date("d.m.Y", strtotime($_POST['arrival']));
$departure = date("d.m.Y", strtotime($_POST['departure']));
```

I am try php 5 and 7 versions. And date is dynamic language

> if page english Jun if page turkish Haz like this

Comment: all works as expected - echo date("d.m.Y", strtotime('11 Jun 2017')); - https://eval.in/959116

Comment: i want to change date format. i want like this 11.06.2017

Comment: i look your eval link working good but dont work our host

Comment: a possible explanation for that would be if arrival input of the post that you get is not a time() in which case it will be considered as time() which will be 1970

Comment: what are your form inputs kindly post it in the question.

Comment: input type hidden field

Comment: thanks for reply. i solve. have a span tags. i remove span tags.

Comment: Also, `strtotime` _Parse about any **English** textual datetime description into a Unix timestamp_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`strtotime` in conjunction with `date` seems to work OK for the given string

```
$str='11 Jun 2017';
echo date('d.m.Y',strtotime( $str ) );
```

outputs

```
11.06.2017
```